# How to change my current unix group

Tags: unix, system-administration

I belong to several user groups (say coder, projectmanager, sudo), for some reason I may not be in a particular group. This happens when I am in a particular directory that belong to a particular group where I need the write access to create new files.  It is quite annoying that I am in a different group.  When I run the groups command, I am listed as in groupA, how do I become groupB?

When I do a search, the top link goes to how to create groups.

Answer (score 1):

If you're an admin, just do it as root or as a user with the appropriate permissions.

If you're trying to avoid that, you can add yourself to the group.  Most systems will let you do that with a simple command:

```bash
sudo usermod -a -G newgroup username
```

Older systems require editing `/etc/group`.  First try `sudo vigr` ("vi group," much like `vipw` for the passwd file) and if that isn't present, you may edit it directly via `sudo vi /etc/group`.

Find the relevant group and append yourself to it.  Users are in the last colon-delimited section and are comma-delimited within that section.  For example, you can add yourself to the "cdrom" and "games" groups:

Before:

```bash
root:x:0:
users:x:100:kemin
cdrom:x:24:
games:x:60:adam
```

After:

```bash
root:x:0:
users:x:100:kemin
cdrom:x:24:kemin
games:x:60:adam,kemin
```

A very quick programmatic approach —which lacks safeties— could look like:

```bash
sudo sed -i '/^games:/s/$/,kemin/; s/:,/:/g' /etc/group
```

I only added one safety above, which accounts for an empty group (no comma needed).  This does not check to ensure you're initially absent from the group, and I didn't use a regex alternation (`/^\(games\|cdrom\):/…`) because non-GNU sed doesn't support it.

(This may not work on systems that lock /etc/group to vigr. The fact that it's hard to get all the safeties correct is why such locking is justified.)

**This will not immediately work!**  You need to log out and log back in, or else sudo as yourself (which is a good way to test without the hassle of logging out), e.g. `sudo -u $USERNAME groups`, or get a new login through a virtual terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) or something like `ssh localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

The command is actually newgrp.  Several other group related commands are:

```
chdgrp  List groups with title and remaining balance
groups  See groups to which you belong with primary group first
chgrp   Change group ownership of directories and files
```

Comment: Will this work if you're not already a member of the group in question?